# JS onEventListener run two separate functions together

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JS code. It is focused on two elements which I want to take into action at once when the event listener is triggered. I tried few codes including the following code.
globe labelColor changes properly. But the curser style of elem is not working. When I changed the code a bit, the cursor of elem worked but then the labelColor of globe stopped working.
How can I take them both in to action at once onLabelHover?
Resource: https://globe.gl/

```
    <script>
         function loadGlobe(){
                var width = document.getElementById("hog4").offsetWidth;
                fetch('datasets/gies.geojson').then(res => res.json()).then(places => {
                    const elem = document.getElementById('hog4');
                    const globe = Globe()
                    .width(width)
                    .globeImageUrl('https://unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/earth-night.jpg')
                    .backgroundImageUrl('https://unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/night-sky.png')
                    .labelText(d => d.properties.name)
                    .labelColor(() => 'rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.75')

                    .onLabelHover((hoverPoint => globe
                        .labelColor(d => d === hoverPoint ? 'steelblue' : 'rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.75')
                    )
                    .then(point =>
                        elem.style.cursor = point ? 'pointer' : null
                    )
                    )
                    (elem)
                });
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: You should provide the complete code for full context

Comment: Hi Anny ! Welcome to SO :) Kindly provide all your code HTML, CSS, and JavaScript [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Joshua

Question Updated

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Question Updated

Comment: where do you want to execute the functions?

Comment: @Joshua It executes on an event such as onhover or onclick.